# Typescript: using Object.keys to iterate over a dictionary

Tags: dictionary, typescript

So I have this interface for my dictionary and I initialize it below.

```
export interface IHash {
    [tagName: string] : string;
}

var x : IHash = {};
x["first"] = "details";
x["second"] = "details";
```

I run `let keys = Object.keys(x);` and then print my `keys` and I get `0` `1`. It looks as if it's outputting the indices. I was expecting it to print `first` and `second`. Would I have to loop through it to get that result?

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://plnkr.co/edit/o8QetWN1AVVP5sKDPUtE?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you doing your printing of `keys`? This is what I see in ts-node

```
> export interface IHash {     [tagName: string] : string; }  var x : IHash = {}; x["first"] = "details"; x["second"] = "details";
'details'
> Object.keys(x);
[ 'first', 'second' ]
>
```

which suggests the error is with your printing rather than the value of keys.

Are you perhaps calling `Object.keys` twice in series? The first time it would give you `[ 'first', 'second' ]` and the second time it would give you `[ '0', '1' ]`